# Git is reading all my computer files, rather than just one folder. How to point git to a different folder?

Tags: git, macos, terminal, bitbucket, git-bash

I'm pretty new to Git (and Stack Overflow). Aside from git `add`, `commit` and `push` - and `pull`, I haven't explored any of the commands just yet.

Every time I open Terminal on my mac, normally when typing `git status` on the main (Macintosh HD) folder, I'll get a response that says, "this is not a git repo." At this point, Ill type `cd [folder path]` and `git status` again, and I'll get an array of files that may need to be committed to Bitbucket. Today, I did the same process, but instead of getting "this is not a git repo," I get git recording changes that need to be committed.

Does anyone know how this happened and how to fix it? Perhaps my question should be: How do I make a certain folder a branch master.

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .CFUserTextEncoding
    .android/
    .bash_history
    .config/
    .gitconfig
    .gitignore_global
    .hgignore_global
    .ssh/
    .viminfo
    Applications/
    Creative Cloud Files/
    Desktop/
    Documents/
    Downloads/
    Google Drive/
    Library/
    Movies/
    Music/
    Pictures/
    Public/
    template/
```

Comment: I think you did `git init` in your user's home directory. just remove `.git` folder - and re-create repo in proper location

Answer (score 4):

Git is telling you that your main Macintosh HD folder is a git repository. This probably happened because you accidentally ran `git init` on your home folder inadvertently either directly or through a 3rd party tool. Change into your Macintosh HD folder and run the following command to check:

```
ls -a
```

If you see a `.git` folder, delete it and your home folder will no longer be a git repository (i.e. everything goes back to normal!)

Comment: you're right, git was installed - not sure when I did that. How do I remove git from here.

Comment: @RommelSantiago What do you mean by "how to remove git from here"? Did my solution about removing the `.git` folder not work for you?

Comment: @RommelSantiago If you found my solution useful, please don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark on the left. Thanks!